# ShowWindow with SetWindowPos(.. SWP_SHOWWINDOW ) does not work. Why?

Tags: mfc

I want an initially not visble control now to show.

I have tried long time with SetWindowPos(.. SWP_SHOWWINDOW ). I have finally abandoned and use now ShowWindow(SW_SHOW).
But still I can not believe and understand why this does not work.

```
BOOL CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDOK);
pWnd->SetWindowPos(this, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);     // This does not work! :( Why?
// pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);       // This works :)

return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
// EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Comment: When you want to make a control invisible, just uncheck "Visible" check box from control property. And you can use ShowWindow(SW_SHOW/SW_HIDE) method in order to hide / show the control ...

Comment: Try adding following flags to the last parameter: `SWP_NOACTIVATE`, `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER`,  `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING` and `SWP_NOZORDER`.

Comment: only additonal SWP_NOZORDER was needed.